# How can i handle Insert from select statement using trigger in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have the following TSQL statements to insert data from one database Table to another database tables, how can i mange this using Trigger?
 the Source table is `[DISCS]` and the destination tables are, 
`[WIBOMH]` is a Master table, `[WIBOMH]` is a header table, `[WIBOMD]` is detail table so 
the orders have to be first insert into `[WIITEM]` then  create a header `[WIBOMH]`

I want to fire this `AFTER INSERT`. when i added a new `DISC` into `DISC` Table i would like to fire the following insert statement

**-- Insert into `[WIITEM]` Table---**

```
     INSERT INTO [WIITEM] 
       ([itemId], [descr],[xdesc],[sales] ,[uOfM] ,[poUOfM] ,[uConvFact],[ref],[type],[status],[unitWgt] )
     SELECT [itemId], [PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION], [SALES_DESCRIPTION], [sales] ,[uOfM] ,[poUOfM] ,[uConvFact],'TESTING', '2','0',[unitWgt]
      FROM [DISCS] 
     WHERE [itemId] NOT IN (SELECT [itemId] FROM [WIITEM])
     AND [makebuy]='Make';
```

**-- Insert into `[WIBOMH]` Table---**

```
  DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();
 INSERT  INTO [WIBOMH] 
   ([bomItem], [bomRev], [rollup], [mult], [autoBuild], [assyLead],[revCmnt],[author],[descr],[qPerLead],[lstMainDt],[revDate],[effStartDate],[ovride] )
 SELECT DISTINCT [bomitem], 'B', '1', '1', '1', '3','TESTING','USER NAME','TESTING','0', FORMAT(@d, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss\.fff', 'en-US') AS 'Format#1',FORMAT(@d, 'yyyyMMdd' , 'en-US') AS 'Format#2',FORMAT(@d, 'yyyyMMdd' , 'en-US') AS 'Format#2','0'
FROM [DISCS] 
 WHERE [bomitem]  IN (SELECT [ItemId] FROM [WIITEM] where type='2')
   AND [bomitem]  NOT IN (SELECT [bomItem] FROM [WIBOMH]);
```

**-- Insert into `[WIBOMD]` Table---**

```
 INSERT INTO [WIBOMD] 
   ([bomItem], [bomRev], [bomEntry], [partId], [qty],[cmnt],[srcLoc],[dType],[lead],[lineNbr])
 SELECT [ItemID], 'B', [bomEntry], [partid], [qty],'TESTING','WSD-DS','0','0', [lineNbr]
 FROM [DISCS]  
 WHERE [ItemID]  IN (SELECT [ItemId] FROM [WIITEM] where type='2')
  AND [ItemID]  NOT IN (SELECT [bomItem] FROM [WIBOMD]);
```

**i tried**

```
INSERT INTO [MITESTCO].[WIITEM] 
   ([itemId], [descr],[xdesc],[sales] ,[uOfM] ,[poUOfM] ,[uConvFact],[ref],[type],[status])

 SELECT 
   [CALC STOCK PN], [PURCHASE DESCRIPTION], [SALES DESCRIPTION], [CALC STOCK PN] ,'EA' ,'EA' ,'1','SYNC FROM PDM', '2','0'--,[APPROX. WGT.]
   FROM inserted
   WHERE [MAKE / BUY]='Make' [CALC STOCK PN] NOT IN (SELECT [itemId] FROM [MIITEM] WHERE itemId NOT LIKE '*-CI');
```

**but i get**

> invalid object [MITESTCO].[WIITEM]

here i got the first trigger working

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[PNSETUP] 
    ON [dbo].[DISCS]
    AFTER insert,UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN
 SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF;
 INSERT INTO MITESTCO.dbo.WIITEM
   ([itemId], [descr],[xdesc],[sales] ,[uOfM] ,[poUOfM] ,[uConvFact],[ref],[type],[status])--,[unitWgt] 
 SELECT [CALC STOCK PN], [PURCHASE DESCRIPTION], [SALES DESCRIPTION], [CALC STOCK PN] ,'EA' ,'EA' ,'1','SYNC FROM PDM', '2','0'--,[APPROX. WGT.]
  FROM [DISCS]
 WHERE [CALC STOCK PN] NOT IN (SELECT [itemId] FROM MITESTCO.dbo.[WIITEM] WHERE itemId NOT LIKE '*-CI')
 AND [MAKE / BUY]='Make';
   SET ANSI_WARNINGS  ON;
```

how can i add the next two insert select statement  to same trigger

Comment: What action/event is supposed to trigger what insert of what data?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: @JenR i want fire trigger after INSERT, Is that what mean by action/event?

Comment: Right like - "When something is inserted into Table A, I want x to happen." - In that case the event is "something is inserted into Table A" and "x" is what the trigger should do.

Comment: Your code samples are at odds with your question.   Look closely at the table names you have in your code samples.   Make sure they are correct.   As written, they only make the question ambiguous and confusing, and definitely unclear.

Comment: So you want to insert into all three of those tables when a row is inserted into DISCS? You would want all three of those inserts in your trigger. But you need to utilize the inserted virtual table so you know what row(s) were inserted. You are going to need to provide us quite a bit more details if you want any kind of detailed help.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you yes that what i am looking for but  i tried something like this `INSERT INTO [MITESTCO].[WIITEM] 
   ([itemId], [descr],[xdesc],[sales] ,[uOfM] ,[poUOfM] ,[uConvFact],[ref],[type],[status])--,[unitWgt] 
 SELECT [CALC STOCK PN], [PURCHASE DESCRIPTION], [SALES DESCRIPTION], [CALC STOCK PN] ,'EA' ,'EA' ,'1','SYNC FROM PDM', '2','0'--,[APPROX. WGT.]
  FROM inserted
 WHERE [MAKE / BUY]='Make';` but i get `invalid object [MITESTCO].[WIITEM] `

Comment: Could you put your attempted code in the question? The comments destroy anything resembling formatting. :D

Comment: @SeanLange sorry about that. updated Thank you

Comment: Does the table/view WIITEM exist in the MITESTCO schema? I have a hunch that MITESTCO is a database and not a schema.

Comment: oh i forgot to add the schema sorry

Comment: @SeanLange I got the first insert trigger working how can i add the next two to the same i added the code which is working or which does the insert

Comment: I don't think that is going to do what you think it will. It will insert every row from DISCS that meets that criteria every single time, meaning you will get a new cartesian for each insert. You need to be pulling rows from the inserted virtual table. Then do the same type of insert into the other two tables in the same trigger.

Comment: @SeanLange so you recommend to use inserted? and how can i implement this using Inserted?

Comment: You select from inserted instead of DISCS. The inserted virtual table will be exactly the same structure as DISCS but will contain only the rows that were just inserted.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange that works for me but one problem the `[descr]` is none NULL field in  destination table and on the source table i have trigger to create a item description so when i first create an item i get `canot insert the NULL into column descr, table MITESTCO.dbo.WITEM; column doesnt allow null. INSERT fails...` i guess the trigger calculate description doesnt fire. How can i change the order?

Comment: To change the order of inserts you would put one before the other one...if the error is that a certain column doesn't allow null then you need to provide a value for that column.

Comment: How can i put one after the other? i changed the alphabetic order that doesn't work and i don't think the second option work in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can use after insert trigger to update the count after each insertion.

Comment: What count? The OP doesn't mention anything about a count. Can you explain how this remotely attempts to answer the original question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a trigger ? Do you need to copy the new rows from the table in real time ?

Triggers will KILL the insert performance of your table.

Consider adding a column DateLastCopied to the source table, and then once a minute

```
declare @now as datetime= getdate()

update sourcetable set DateLastCopied=@now where DateLastCopied is null

insert into targetTable(..)
select ...
FROM sourcetable where DateLastCopied=@now
```

Comment: is this will be done automatically? I am using sqlserver express

Comment: The only reason i need a trigger is to automate the process